# Replacing a document in MongoDB when the imported document has a same id (mongoimport)

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to `mongoimport` a jsonarray file to my MongoDB.

I used the command below for my previous import and has been successful:

`mongoimport.exe --host <host> --db <db> --collection <collection> --type json --file <file> --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username <id> --password <pw>`

This time I am trying to import another jsonarray that contains the same structured documents but some of them have same `_id`s as some documents that are already in the MongoDB.

[image]

This is the structure of a document.

I am concered because the `_id` field is not an `ObjectId` but just an integer that I manually labeled, so it would not consider new documents with the same `_id` (but with other modified fields) as the same object and will not overwrite it.

How can I overwrite the document that has the same `_id` as the imported documents (and of course add new documents that do not overlap with any of the documents in the DB)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I should have read the documentation more carefully.

With `--mode upsert`, `mongoimport` replaces existing documents in the database that match a document in the import file with the document from the import file. Documents that do not match an existing document in the database are inserted as usual. By default `mongoimport` matches documents based on the `_id` field. Use --upsert Fields to specify the fields to match against.